# Create a Zip file on the fly and make it available for download in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, zip, on-the-fly

I have an **ASP.NET Web Forms** application. Once the user clicks on a **download link**, I need to create several **XMLs** file **on the fly**, zip them and prompt the user with a download dialog.

I already made the function to download a single XML file and it works correctly. The link in the **download.aspx** file is:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlDownload" Text="Download" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("GetFile.aspx?LicenseGuid={0}", Eval("ProductId")) %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The function in the **GetFile.aspx** code behind:

```
Dim xmlFile = _productServices.GetXMLFilePerProductId(ProductId)
Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlFile)

Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=some_name.xml")

xdoc.Save(Response.Output)
Response.End()
```

How can I create a ZIP file on the fly and pack a couple of XML files, created on the fly as well?

PS: answers in both C# and VB.NET are welcome

Comment: We don't give teh codez here - you have been around long enough to know this. Please explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I know SO policy, I didn't want the code, just an overview of the process that I have to follow in order to implement the function. At the moment I was able to create a ZIP file, just starting from file created and saved in the HD

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ZipFile class of the CodeFluent Entities Runtime Client package :
[Link here](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/08/24/exploring-the-codefluent-runtime-zipfile/)

This library allows the use of streams only, meaning that you don't have a create a temporary file on the filesystem.

Comment: Most zip libraries work on streams. Including the ones in the FCL/BCL.

Comment: Yes hopefully. That one is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you like you can go for .net GZip or Deflate streams and can develop a solution of your own or  A better option is to use [SharpZip .net Library](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx), that has managed Code.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you think the SharpZip is a better library?

Comment: @CiccioMiami, its open source, well tested and provide a quick API to acheive what you desire.

Comment: SharpZipLib is slow "For CPU performance and memory usage reasons, and contrary to other popular .NET zip implementations (http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/, or http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), CodeFluent Entities’ ZipFile implementation is unmanaged."

Comment: @Bgi SharpZip is the popular `icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib`